# UPDATE mysql front end

Tags: jquery, crud

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wb7wb.png)
 I have a screen shot of my form to execute the put method on the front end but when ever I try to execute it I get no response at all from the network tab below I have my server code and front end code

```
   app.put('/movielist/updateMovie/:id',(req,res) =>{
  const  id = req.params.id;
  const update = req.body;
  mysqlConnection.query("UPDATE movielist SET ? WHERE idmovielist = ?", [update, id], function (err, results) {
    if (!err) {
      res.send("Movie list is updated");
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});


$(function(){
      function getOneMovie(id) {
              $.ajax({
                  url: 'http://localhost:3000/movielist' + id,
                  method: 'GET',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  success: function (data) {
                      $($("#updateForm")[0].movieId).val(data._id);
                      $($("#updateForm")[0].intNum).val(data.intNum);
                      $($("#updateForm")[0].name).val(data.name);
                      $($("#updateForm")[0].thumnail_path).val(data.thumnail_path);
                      $($("#updateForm")[0].description).val(data.description);
                      $($("#updateForm")[0].year_released).val(data.year_released);
                      $($("#updateForm")[0].language_released).val(data.language_released);
                      $("#updateForm").show();
                  }
              });
          }

          $("#movieAdded").click(function (a) {
            console.log("movieAdded Click")
              let mydata = {
                  idmovielist: $($("#newForm")[0].intNum).val(),
                  name: $($("#newForm")[0].name).val(),
                  thumnail_path: $($("#newForm")[0].thumnail_path).val(),
                  description: $($("#newForm")[0].description).val(),
                  year_released: $($("#newForm")[0].year_released).val(),
                  language_released: $($("#newForm")[0].language_released).val(),
              }
              displayMovie(mydata);
              console.log("Hidden")
              $("#newForm").trigger("reset");
              $("#newForm").toggle();
              console.log("Hidden")
              a.preventDefault();
          });
          function displayMovie(mydata) {
              $.ajax({
                  method: "POST",
                  url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist/addMovie",
                  dataType: "json",
                  data: mydata,
                  success: function (data) {
                      console.log(data);
                  }
              });
          }

          function loadButton() {
              $(".editMovie").click(function (a) {
                  getOneMovie($($(this)[0]).data("movieId"));
                  a.preventDefault();
              });

              $(".deleteMovie").click(function (a) {
                  deleteMovie($($(this)[0]).data("movieId"));
                  a.preventDefault();
              });
          }
             loadButton();
          function putMovie(id, data) {
              $.ajax({
                  url: 'http://localhost:3000/movielist/updateMovie/' + id,
                  method: 'PUT',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  data: data,
                  success: function (data) {
                      console.log(data);
                      getOneMovie();
                  }
              });
          }

          $("#updateMovie").on("click", function (a) {
              let data = {
                  idmovielist: $($("#updateForm")[0].intNum).val(),
                  name: $($("#updateForm")[0].name).val(),
                  thumnail_path: $($("#updataForm")[0].thumnail_path).val(),
                  description: $($("#updateForm")[0].description).val(),
                  year_released: $($("#updateForm")[0].year_released).val(),
                  language_released: $($("#updateForm")[0].language_released).val(),
              }

              putMovie($($("#updateForm")[0].movieId).val(), data);
              $("#updateForm").trigger("reset");
              $("#updateForm").toggle();
              a.preventDefault();

          });


          function deleteMovie(id) {
              $.ajax({
                  url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist/" + id,
                  method: 'DELETE',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  success: function (data) {
                      console.log(data);
                  }
              });
          }

});
```

So basically this put works on my back end but when I execute it on the front end their is no response so is their a way I can fix this and is their something wrong in my front end and also I get this mycrud.js:79 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'thumnail_path' of undefined

thumnail_path: $($("#updataForm")[0].thumnail_path).val(),
this part above is saying it is undefined

Comment: the query in the error message is not the same one in the code.

Comment: The query in the error message has extra quotes around `tapori` and an extra comma after it.

Comment: The query in the code is missing the value to assign to `year_released`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running this query against an actual database console?

You need to set `year_released`=[some value]. SET requires an argument to change the value of the field.

Also in the error you're showing, you have double single quotes around the value `tapori`. That should have only one escaped \' on either side of it.

Comment: ok nvm I got it working but I need help getting to work on the front end